# How to search words one by one in webpage using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

am doing one automation using python with selenium, need to find out the job.
I am stuck in this part, which means I have to search for each job name one by one on the web page and then click on its respective report link

my code to get current day running job:

```
job_details = {
    "RTR": {
        "ROWH100929": {"Monday": job1,job2,job3,job4"],
                       "Tuesday": ["job1,job2"],
                       "Wednesday":["job1,job2"],
                       "Thursday":["job1,job4"],
                       "Friday": ["job1,job2"]},                       
    },
    "TCR": {
    **** job details****
},                       
    "MAA": {
    **** job details****
    }
}
    day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%A')
output_list = []
for site, machines in job_details.items():
    for machine, jobs in machines.items():
        if day in jobs:
            running_jobs = jobs[day]
            if len(running_jobs) > 0:
                output = f"Below jobs running in mentioned Site == {site}, machine == {machine}, Day == {day}\n"
                #print(f"Below jobs running in mentioned Site == {site}, machine == {machine}, Day == {day}")
                for job in running_jobs:
                    output += job + "\n"
                output_list.append(output)
                print(output)
```

next tried to search job one by one in webpage but its not getting searched properly, once the job name is getting searched properly next need to click on respective site report link, stuck in this part

```
            for job in running_jobs:
                output += job + "\n"
                options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                options.add_argument('--incognito')
                s = Service("C:/Users/Public/DXS/drivers/chromedriver.exe")
                options.add_argument("--lang=en")
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
                driver.maximize_window()
                driver.get("https://nlp.ope.applis.fr/ope/runsIndex.html")
                #options.add_argument('--headless')
                today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
                time.sleep(5)
                for j in job:
                    try:
                        job_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//td[contains(text(),'{j}')]")
                        print(job_element.text)
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        print(f"{j} not found in the webpage")
            output_list.append(output)
            print(output)
```

my web page looks like

[image]

Comment: what is the problem with your current strategy?

Comment: @JonSG Searching for job names in webpage one by one is not yielding correct results. I have tried several methods, but none of them seem to work, After searching for the job, need to click on the report

Comment: If you code is exactly as you posted, then one issue is that `["job1,job2"]` is a list of a single string, not a list of two strings.

Comment: When I run into something like this, I try to boil it down to the simplest form... Make a copy of the script(s). Get rid of reading from other files, etc. and just hardcode values. No loops... just get one pass working. Then slowly add complexity back in... loops, etc. until you either find the problem or it's all working.